# How to print a string to another application's dialogue box?

Tags: java, python

Maybe I wasn't searching the right key words, but I couldn't find anything on printing to another application's dialogue box. Most of my searches came to filling a web page, but I want to print a string to dialogue boxes of other applications like you would for logging into game launchers.

Comment: Those don't usually print from one application to the other directly. One application outputs its data *somewhere* (often times using default console output) then the other reads that output and copies it to the dialogue box. Unless one application can be embedded in the other, but that doesn't sound like what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operating system will usually not allow you to write into the memory of other application. So if the other application is unwilling to take your input, it's practically not possible.

If it is willing to take your input, there are several ways:

- **Accepting input through the standard input** - This means you need to open it as a process and write into the output pipe
- **Having an open web API** - the application is listening on a network port and accepting connections (e.g. HTTP) so you can send HTTP requests to it (even from the same machine)
- **Listening for any other inter-process communication method** - either subscribed to a broker you can publish on, or directly listening for connections (let's say on UNIX-domain socket).

If the application is not listening to anything, nor using any shared resource/memory piece, then there's effectively no way.

Unless...

You wrap the application up in an application of yours. The same way the most game launchers and even game cheats do. Then your application will be completely responsible to proxy the output of the other application to the end-user. Your can take its output, augment it a little bit (e.g. add some texts to a rectangle) and then render it to the user.

Comment: That explains why there's nothing on the web about this. Thank you for taking the time to write out a detailed explanation!